# upload file within a specific folder in a bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm using `gem 'aws-sdk-s3'` and I'm successfully able to upload my files on **AWS** bucket using **Active-Storag**e but I don't know how can I upload my files in a specific folder in my bucket?

Comment: Please share, what you tried.

Comment: I'm uploading my restaurant's pics by postman,  pictures are associated with my Restaurant model, everything is fine but I want to upload those pics in a specific folder which is already present in my bucket.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476114/uploading-a-file-using-the-ruby-sdk-to-amazon-s3?

Comment: Just include the **full path** in the key, eg `images/asian/padthai.jpg`.

Comment: im sending my image from postman , and before saving i got these params, 
  params[:restaurant][:image] 

#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fe0742222c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20200917-1-1gyikg8.jpeg>, @original_filename="download.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"restaurant[image]\"; filename=\"download.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">


now I don't know where is the key you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the object, you specify the object key as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#initialize-instance_method:

> Constructor Details
> #initialize(bucket_name, key, options = {}) ⇒ Object #initialize(options = {}) ⇒ Object
>
> Returns a new instance of Object.
>
> Overloads:

```
#initialize(bucket_name, key, options = {}) ⇒ Object

Parameters:
    bucket_name (String)
    key (String)

Options Hash (options):
    :client (Client)
#initialize(options = {}) ⇒ Object

Options Hash (options):
    :bucket_name (required, String)
    :key (required, String)
    :client (Client)
```

S3 doesn't really have folders, it just has keys.  Then the GUI uses separators in the key to mimic folders.  So if you want your object to be in a specific "folder" then make sure the key for that object contains that folder path.
From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html:

> Amazon S3 has a flat structure instead of a hierarchy like you would
> see in a file system. However, for the sake of organizational
> simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a
> means of grouping objects. Amazon S3 does this by using a shared name
> prefix for objects (that is, objects have names that begin with a
> common string). Object names are also referred to as key names.
>
> For example, you can create a folder on the console named **photos** and
> store an object named **myphoto.jpg** in it. The object is then stored
> with the key name **photos/myphoto.jpg**

Comment: im sending my image from postman , and before saving i got these params, params[:restaurant][:image] #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fe0742222c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20200917-1-1gyikg8.jpeg>, @original_filename="download.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"restaurant[image]\"; filename=\"download.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"> now I don't know where is the key you are talking about –

Comment: and I'm using active storage and someone told me that this is not possible when  u  are using active storage